# Get Regular Product Price with Tax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to get the regular product price with tax included but I cannot find any WooCommerce function or variable with this purpose.

To get the regular product price **without** tax I'm using:

```
$price = $product->get_regular_price();
```

But how can I get the regular product price WITH tax included?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array('price' => $price ) );
wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array('price' => $specialPrice ) );
```

LE: You need to add the price as the second argument to wc_get_price_including_tax()

Comment: Might be these line solved the problem. Add some description in your answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code -

product price with tax -   `wc_get_price_including_tax($product);`

product price without tax - `wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product);`

Comment: I have tried `wc_get_price_including_tax($product);` but unfortunately it returns the sale price (aka promotional price, reduced price) with taxes, not the base price (aka old price) with taxes.

Comment: wc_get_price_including_tax($product,array('price'=>$product->get_regular_price()))